# Microsoft Excel 2013 display format issue

Tags: microsoft-excel-2013

I was trying to write set numbers in a cell with "general" format, eg 597619354453, but when I went on to the next row it ends up displaying as 5.97619E+11. Any idea how I can set it to display as the original number?

Answer (score 0):

If you place an apostrophe (') preceeding the number, it will be treated as text and the entire set of digits will be presented, if the cell width is large enough. Alternatively, set the cell format to number with zero decimal places, but that's not consistent with your question.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know this is beacuse the columns are too thin to display the data correctly, or the standard number format is not specified. Excel is only precise to 15 digits.

Try to right click the cell and select Format cells and select Number:

[image]